# "no token found" in micronaut app after authentication with OpenID / Keycloak

Tags: openid, keycloak, micronaut

I'm struggling to build a Micronaut App which is implementing OpenID authentication with Keycloak.

To keep it simple, I took the Micronaut Okta sample (https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-oauth2-okta/guide/index.html) and changed the entries in application.yml to address our Keycloak server, modified the link "/oauth/login/okta" in home.html to "/oauth/login/keycloak" and added a logger for io.micronaut.security to the logback.xml.

The authentication seems to work in some way (Keycloak login shows up and after login browser returns to the Micronaut site), but the Micronaut site seems not to "recognize" it.

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

application.yml:

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: examples
    server:
        port: 8080
        cors:
            enabled: true
    security:
        enabled: true # <1>
        oauth2:
            enabled: true
            clients:
                keycloak:
                    client-secret: 'd3e283af-3a97-4c1f-b76e-ed39d3c28ca2'
                    client-id: 'mykctest-admin'
                    openid:
                        issuer: 'https://login.mykeycloak.org/auth/realms/mykctest'
        token:
            jwt:
                enabled: true # <6>
                cookie:
                   enabled: true # <7>
                signatures:
                    secret:
                        generator:
                            secret: pleaseChangeThisSecretForANewOne
        endpoints:
            logout:
                enabled: true # <8>
                get-allowed: true # <9>
```

Partial log output:

```
> ... 16:14:22.224 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-30] TRACE
> i.m.s.o.e.a.r.DefaultOpenIdAuthorizationResponseHandler - Token
> validation succeeded. Creating a user details 16:14:22.225
> [nioEventLoopGroup-1-30] TRACE i.m.s.o.r.DefaultOauthController -
> Authentication succeeded. User [6a316b0d-4d1e-4a8b-a06b-96e6b6363229]
> is now logged in 16:14:22.225 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-30] DEBUG
> i.m.s.t.j.g.c.JWTClaimsSetGenerator - Setting expiration to 3600
> 16:14:22.226 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-30] DEBUG
> i.m.s.t.j.g.c.JWTClaimsSetGenerator - Generated claim set: { <contains
> usernames and access tokens...> } 16:14:22.229
> [nioEventLoopGroup-1-30] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.g.c.JWTClaimsSetGenerator -
> Generated claim set: { <contains usernames and access tokens...> }
> 16:14:22.245 [pool-2-thread-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in
> Authorization header 16:14:22.245 [pool-2-thread-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in
> Authorization header 16:14:22.245 [pool-2-thread-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.t.reader.DefaultTokenResolver - Request GET, /, no token found.
> 16:14:22.245 [pool-2-thread-2] DEBUG
> i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - No Authentication fetched for
> request. GET /. 16:14:22.245 [pool-2-thread-2] DEBUG
> i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /. The
> rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule
> authorized the request. ...
```

Comment: Looks like the JWT cookie token reader/writer is not being used for some reason. Have you tried the completed app in the guide?

Comment: Yes I took the complete sample. The only additional modification was to add a truststore to the run configuration because the certificate of the keycloak server was not trustable.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the cookie being too large. Keycloak seems to generate larger than normal tokens that get stored in the JWT. In the latest snapshot of Oauth those parameters are not stored in the JWT unless configured to do so. Please try with the latest snapshot